# quick limit question

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I'm trying to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\Big(\frac{x^{n}}{n^{k}}\Big) \rightarrow \infty, x > 0, k =1,2,\dots$

By the ratio test we have $\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{k}} \frac{n^{k}}{x^{n}} = x\Big(\frac{n}{n+1}\Big)^{k} \rightarrow x$. For $ x > 1$

but then I am not seeing how to proceed. Also, I presume I'd need to consider the case $ 0 < x \leq 1$ separately since then the numerator would tend to $0$.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use L'Hospital's rule to solve this.

Consider $n$ as real variable. Let $x $ be greater than $1$.
Then both numerator and denominator would go to $\infty$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$.

Now $\frac{d^k x^n}{dn} = x^n (ln(x)^k$ and differentiating $n^k$  $\,k$ times would give me a constant with respect to $n$. Then if we apply the limit the answer will be $\infty$.
Suppose $x$ is between $0$ and $1$ then the limit value will be $0$.